# Confidence interval on the standard error of a fit parameter

Tags: statistics

I need to find a confidence interval on the standard error of a fit parameter. The key information that I need to calculate and report is the standard error of a fit parameters, not the fit parameters themselves.

I'm simulating a physical system that results in the following simple linear regression equation:

$\vec{y}=\vec{x}_1 \beta_1 +\vec{x}_2 \beta_2 $

For physical reasons I have left off the constant term $\beta_0$. The data for $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$ is determined and assumed not to have any error. I then create my $\vec{y}$ data from a physical process but then add an instant of error. The physical process gives me the mean to a Poisson process I then a pick an instance from the Poisson distribution. I  also have to quantize the resulting number into a digital count. Therefor the values in the $\vec{y}$ are integers.

I'm currently using Mathematica to do my fitting which works well and I can get the values for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ along with the standard error for each parameter.  Below is what [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html) calls this in their documentation:

```
"MeanPredictionErrors"  standard errors for mean predictions
```

If I run the experiment again and generate a new instance of noise for my $\vec{y}$ data, I will get a different value for the  standard error for each parameter. I could run the experiment over and over to get an estimate on the variance of the standard error for each parameter. But this can take a lot of computer time.

*Question:*
Is there a better way to find the variance on the standard errors for fit parameters?

*Sad backstory:*
Others in my field that have done this calculation have simply picked a random seed and run the regression once then report the standard errors for fit parameters and completely ignore the real variability in the standard errors.